# Changing user_nicename

Tags: php, database, users, login, mysql

**user_nicename** has the same value with **user_login**. I want to change **user_nicename** value only by using code snippet into functions.php or wp-config.php. Is it possible without using phpmyadmin or any plugin?

Comment: Note that `user_nicename` and `user_login` are separate for a reason, and they aren't the same.  `user_nicename` is the URL sanitized version of `user_login`, changing it to something else might break things in unexpected ways. Perhaps you actually wanted to change `display_name`?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell ,

I wanted to change user_nicename only because if I didn't change it, hackers can detect it easy via url and attack to my blog. (brute force). The blog is more secure now.

Comment: usernames and IDs aren't secret, they can be fetched via the REST API, XML RPC, even the CSS classes and URLs in a webpage. Doing this does nothing to improve your security, and if your sites security depends on these things being secret then you have major problems

Comment: @TomJNowell Could you please clarify what kind of problems do you mean? I didn't change user_login table. I changed user_nicename only. Also I blocked XML-RPC and REST API requests. There is no css class about user_login. My blog is minimal. user_nicename is used to create author permalink only. Hackers can discover username by author query. So I changed it only.

Comment: e.g. on the author pages, when you comment on things. Also by blocking the REST API you're crippling a number of plugins and core features, e.g. the 5.0 block editor, Yoast SEO, Jetpack, etc User IDs and logins aren't a secret, they were never meant to be a secret, and exposing them shouldn't be a security risk. What we have here is security theatre. The only reason `user_nicename` exists is because if you have an umlaut or other non-URL friendly character in your username, it wouldn't match when you did the query, so it sanitises it ahead of time for performance

Comment: Additionally, there's the possibility that you've broken a handful of APIs such as `get_user_by` by messing with some fundamental assumptions. Plugins may throw the odd curveball unexpected error. All for something which can be undone by visiting `yoursite.com/author/user_nicename` then looking at the body CSS class, or the RSS feed, etc. This is a bad idea

Comment: I will change it as default again :) Thank you for detailed information :) @TomJNowell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`wp_update_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/):

```
wp_update_user( array(
    'ID'            => 123,
    'user_nicename' => 'value'
) );
```

Just replace `123` with the proper user ID, and `value` with the preferred `user_nicename` value.

The function also enables you to change the value of other fields in the WordPress users table (`wp_users`).

Comment: If you do this, will Wordpress still enforce the rule that nicenames must be unique, and modify it if needed?  If not, chaos could ensue.

Comment: @JimWorrall, `wp_update_user()` uses [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) which does ensure that the `user_nicename` is unique, and back then, the purpose of this answer was merely to let @SerdarKoçak know that `wp_update_user()` could be used to programmatically update the `user_nicename` value. What I didn't include in the answer, though, is that `user_login` can't be updated without using custom SQL.